# Notification setLights() Default Value?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I want to create a custom notification. So i want to change the lights and the tone.
I use the `NotificationCompat.Builder` for that.

Now i want to change the Lights via `setLights()`;
Works fine. But i want set the default value of the `onMS` and `offMS`. I haven't find something about that.

Can anybody help me to find the default values?
Here is the documentation for that: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setLights(int, int, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setLights%28int,%20int,%20int%29)

Answer (score 8):

See the [Android source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/9e27e114af071cd5ffdc5d995015220d6d19778c/core/res/res/values/config.xml#1100) for answer:

```
<!-- Default color for notification LED. -->
<color name="config_defaultNotificationColor">#ffffffff</color>
<!-- Default LED on time for notification LED in milliseconds. -->
<integer name="config_defaultNotificationLedOn">500</integer>
<!-- Default LED off time for notification LED in milliseconds. -->
<integer name="config_defaultNotificationLedOff">2000</integer>
```

However different ROMs might have different values for these. For example mine returns `5000` for `config_defaultNotificationLedOff`. So you might want to fetch them at runtime:

```
Resources resources = context.getResources(),
          systemResources = Resources.getSystem();
notificationBuilder.setLights(
    ContextCompat.getColor(context, systemResources
        .getIdentifier("config_defaultNotificationColor", "color", "android")),
    resources.getInteger(systemResources
        .getIdentifier("config_defaultNotificationLedOn", "integer", "android")),
    resources.getInteger(systemResources
        .getIdentifier("config_defaultNotificationLedOff", "integer", "android")));
```

According to [diff](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/670f93283b5e2445c58998153de9c476acddc37b%5E%21/core/res/res/values/config.xml), these attributes are guaranteed to exist on Android 2.2+ (API level 8+).

Answer (score 2):

@Aleks G
that do not help. I have the latest update from the compat libaray. But Eclipse say `build()` isn avalaible.
I dont no why. The docu says yes and you...

This is my current code:

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder notify = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    notify.setLights(Color.parseColor(led), 5000, 5000);
    notify.setAutoCancel(true);
    notify.setSound(Uri.parse(tone));
    notify.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_kw);
    notify.setContentTitle("Ttiel");
    notify.setContentText("Text");
    Intent showIntent = new Intent(context, Activity_Login.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, showIntent, 0); 
    notify.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notify.getNotification());
```

runs perfectly. But not with the default `onMS` and `offMS` in `setLights()` :(

Comment: build() was added as a synonym for getNotification() in API 16, but they do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with:

```
Notifictaion notf = new Notification.Builder(this).setXXX(...).....build();
notf.ledARGB = <your color>;
notf.ledOnMS = <your value>;  //or skip this line to use default
notf.ledOffMS = <your value>; //or skip this line to use default
```

Basically, don't use `setLights` on the notification builder.  Instead, build the notification first - then you have access to individual fields for the lights.

**Update:** this is the actual copy/paste from my sample project, which compiles and works fine on android 2.1 and uses blue colour for LED:

```
Notification notf = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setTicker("This is the sample notification")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.my_icon)
    .build();
notf.ledARGB = 0xff0000ff;
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(1, notf);
```

Comment: Sorry but this is confused. U use Notification notf =.. Builder. That doesn't run. Also i can't call build(). (I use as smallest SDK 8). So i must call builder.getNotification();. But this also do not run...

Comment: @StefanM. I updated my answer with the actual code from my sample project.  `NotificationCompat.Builder.build` is available from API level 3.

Comment: Only more confused... build() is'nt available says Eclipse! And the setIcon too...

Comment: @StefanM. Sorry, it should be `setSmallIcon` and `setLargeIcon`.  `build` is available - and my eclipse happily takes it for API level 7.  Maybe you should updated your compatibility library.